# How to refresh analysis service database using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssas

What Powershell command refreshes a database in analysis service (SSAS)?  I would like to see server parameter and database name parameter too.  Also, I want to do a full refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -Server servername -DatabaseName "databasename" -RefreshType Full
```

Comment: Note that Invoke-ASCmd and Invoke-ProcessASDatabase are different alternatives for doing the same thing.  You don't run both.